# Can I convert an app based of Azure serverless functions to traditional asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, .net, azure-functions

There is a piece of code, a webserver backend, thats written as a whole bunch of azure functions - and predictably its terribly slow - kind of the mistake that someone has pointed out in this blog - https://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2019/10/02/dont-use-azure-functions-as-a-web-application.html

Is there an easy way to convert an Azure functions based web server to a traditional simple .NET server ? I mean "magically" without rearchitecting the whole thing. Sorry I am a newbie to this whole web/azure thing and trying to find my way around an existing code base

Comment: No, there's no "magic switch" or utility to do this - as this really **IS** a **re-architecting** job, and architecting is still a human endeavor.

Comment: the answer is yes, but as @marc_s pointed out - no easy way of doing that

Comment: Thanks for the responses, does anyone really build a web server application using azure functions ? To me as the blog says, it doesnt seem like azure functions is built for building a full web application - rather it seems to be for handling a single standalone asynchronous application which doesnt have realtime needs

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments, there isn't a easy way to convert the function to a web app directly. But I think it is not different for us to implement it. You just need to copy the copy the body of your function code and create some function or apis in your web app with the code which you copied from function. You may need to adjust some parameters in your apis in web app.

Apart from this, you can also call these functions in your new app code(without rewrite the function code in your new app). I think the whole process will not be difficult.